# Project in C. Not sure about way i did it my project

Tags: c

Hi I just done my project for school. I am just not sure about way i did it.

I have files:

headers.h - i keep here all headers of functions (declaration) and public variables.

save_sunctions.c - definition of some functions

move_sunctions.c - definition of some functions

loop_sunctions.c - definition of some functions

goone_sunctions.c - definition of some functions

main.c - in this file i use all of these functions.

Is it good? Or I should use "extern" or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is more conventional to have a one-to-one relationship between header files and source files.  That way you can, in another project, include just a portion of the code, without including header declarations for lots of functions that do not have definitions in the project.

So, for each `.c` file have a corresponding `.h` file with the same name that declares each function in the `.c` file.

You will need to add what is known as a [*guard*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_guard) to each header file to ensure it is only included once.  Guards look like this:

```
#ifndef GO_FUNCTIONS_GUARD
#define GO_FUNCTIONS_GUARD
.../* declarations go here
#endif
```

As for `extern`, there's no need for that in what you describe. Just stick to header files.

Comment: Let say that some function in move_functions.c use another functions from another file like go_functions.c. So I should put declaration of this function from go_funstions.c to move_funstions.h to be able to use it. Am I correct?

Comment: In this example, you declare the functions in go_functions.h. Then in move_functions.c you `#include "go_functions.h"`.

Comment: Ok, and if save_functions.c also use some function from go_functions.c, the header go_functions.h will be redeclared ;(

Comment: @Domiik Very good point, well spotted. You need a guard. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should try to keep all similar code together.  In my opinion, each `.c` file should have it's own `.h` file to refer to.  I think you probably over separated the files, but that is subject to interpretation.